# How to use captcha botdetect in MVC Core 6.0?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, captcha, asp.net-core-6.0, botdetect

Hi I am trying to implement the captcha of botdetect in MVC Core 6. After a lots of search i don't find any solution for MVC Core 6. If Anyone have an idea for using on mvc 6.0 than tell me.

steps completed on my side are:

1. Installation of Captcha completed.
2. created a captchahelper class for for design implementation here is the code:

   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Web;
   using BotDetect.Web.Mvc;

   ```
    namespace ePost.Common
    {
        public static class CaptchaHelper
        {
            public static MvcCaptcha GetRegistrationCaptcha()
            {
                // create the control instance
                MvcCaptcha registrationCaptcha = new MvcCaptcha("RegistrationCaptcha");
                // set up client-side processing of the Captcha code input textbox
                registrationCaptcha.UserInputID = "CaptchaCode";
                registrationCaptcha.HelpLinkEnabled = false;
                registrationCaptcha.HelpLinkText = "";
                registrationCaptcha.HelpLinkUrl = "#";
                // Captcha settings
                registrationCaptcha.ImageSize = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 50);
                registrationCaptcha.CodeLength = 4;

                return registrationCaptcha;
            }
            public static MvcCaptcha GetLoginCaptcha()
            {
                // create the control instance
                MvcCaptcha loginCaptcha = new MvcCaptcha("LoginCaptcha");

                // set up client-side processing of the Captcha code input textbox
                loginCaptcha.UserInputID = "CaptchaCode";
                loginCaptcha.HelpLinkEnabled = false;
                loginCaptcha.HelpLinkText = "";
                loginCaptcha.HelpLinkUrl = "#";
                // Captcha settings
                loginCaptcha.ImageSize = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 50);
                loginCaptcha.CodeLength = 4;

                return loginCaptcha;

            }
        }
    }
   ```
3. Now i am trying to display this captcha on view with using this code:

   @{
                              MvcCaptcha loginCaptcha = CaptchaHelper.GetLoginCaptcha();
                          }

   ```
                     @Html.Captcha(loginCaptcha)        

                      <div class="form-card">
                          <div class="mt-4" style="margin-bottom:-40px;">
                              <label for="captchareg" class="fieldlabels">Type Above Code:</label>
                              <input asp-for="CaptchaCode" class="form-input captchaVal valid space-not textbox" id="captchareg" maxlength="10" />
                              <span class="b-placeholderreg">Type Above Code</span>
                              <span asp-validation-for="CaptchaCode" class="text-danger"></span>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </fieldset>
   ```
4. @Html.Captcha(loginCaptcha)    this line of code is working on normal MVC but it is not working in MVC core 6. Am i missing something please tell me. is there any need to inject this captcha service in program.cs file than please tell me.

If Anyone have a aolution for this please tell me.

Answer (score -1):

Juding from the namespace `using BotDetect.Web.Mvc;` you referred, you codes were for Asp.Net(Not core), you have to find a [solution](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AspNetCore.ReCaptcha) for .net core

Comment: 1. The code is actually for .Net core. It's documented here: https://captcha.com/mvc/mvc-captcha.html#mvc5-captcha 2. The answer is not even a solution, it's just referring to a totally different library.